# How do i create a graphql schema for a self referencing data hierarchy?

Tags: graphql, relayjs

This doesnt work because the type refers to its self in the routes field definition:

```
  var routeType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'MessageRoute',
  fields: {
    name: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    routes: {
      type: new GraphQLList(routeType),
      resolve: (route) => {
        return route.routes;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

so how do I do it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A GraphQL type can refer to itself (or refer to another type defined later in a file) by defining `fields` as a function that returns an object rather than an object. The function will be called after the page has been fully parsed.

For your example:

```js
var routeType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'MessageRoute',
  fields: function () {
    return {
      name: {
        type: GraphQLString
      },
      routes: {
        type: new GraphQLList(routeType),
        resolve: (route) => {
          return route.routes;
        }
      }
    };
  }
});
```

Or, if you're using ES6, a nice shorthand for this using arrow functions:

```js
var routeType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'MessageRoute',
  fields: () => ({
    name: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    routes: {
      type: new GraphQLList(routeType),
      resolve: (route) => {
        return route.routes;
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Cool thanks, any idea how I write the react side of things without getting a stack overflow?

Comment: Is there a way for the result of a graphql query to be self referencing? I understand this is possible in XML - I have quite a basic understanding of GraphQL at this point. Is it possible that the graphql engine resolves XML instead of JSON?

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to point out that you can use a function for any property inside an object using [Javascript getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

So instead of wrapping the whole `fields` property within a function you can use a function just for the `type` property like this:

```
var routeType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'MessageRoute',
  fields: {
    name: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    routes: {
      get type() {
         return new GraphQLList(routeType)
      },
      resolve: (route) => {
        return route.routes;
      }
    }
  }
});
```